# Version of Eclipse for Android Development

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm having trouble choosing version of Eclipse for Android development. I downloaded Eclipse Mars 1, and it does not show `ANDROID NEW` so I have to know now what I download.

I have read a few sites online and they said that you go to `File > new > Project > Android`.
I'm using Eclipse mars 1 just to know.
I did not have that so that is why I need to know what I need to use and I do not want to use Android Studio. Is it just Eclipse that I need or a plugin also that is needed. So which version of Eclipse should I use?

Comment: Google no longer support Eclipse for Android development, you should be looking at Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To code Android applications in Eclipse you need to install the Android ADT to the Eclipse you use ( In your case it is Mars) it is done through `Help -> Install New Software`, then in combo add "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ " then select the "Developer Tools" and hit "Next" and then "Finish".
Then restart Eclipse and perform `File > new > Project > Android`, you will find it. For more info refer this [site](http://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-setup-android-for-eclipse-ide) But I recommend you to shift to `Android Studio` as it the Official Android Development IDE now

Comment: This link may also helpful to you as it contain Screen shots of the installation process. [link](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Setup-Eclipse-for-Android-App-Development/?ALLSTEPS)

Comment: Yeah but i still do not understand

Comment: What part is it that you don't understand

Comment: @Lama , This is just like adding `plugins` to you Internet browser, after you added a plugin you can use it in your browser(for example: adding `Shockwave Flash` plugin) same as here we add the Android Development Tools (ADT) plugin to Eclipse so that we can use the same IDE for Android App development

Comment: @Lama if you can, accept my answer as the correct one, without accepting the exact 100% duplicate answer of mine posted by `doggyismad` which is posted after 2 days from my answer. It is because when others search for your question, they will see the  copied answer without the hyperlink referred by me from `site` word, which in turn make the answer incomplete.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse require ADT plugin to support Android development.

[ADT 23.0.7](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) (August 2015) requires Eclipse Indigo (Version 3.7.2) or higher is required.

But the ADT plugins are no longer [supported](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html) by Google.

> Support for the Android Developer Tools (ADT) in Eclipse has ended, per our announcement. You should migrate your app development projects to Android Studio as soon as possible.

So it's recommended to download [Android Studios](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) for Android development.

Answer (score 1):

Try following the instructions in the link bellow.

http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Setup-Eclipse-for-Android-App-Development/

Answer (score 1):

*I have figured out how to do it finally!!!*

And i tried it twice

This is all you have to do download adt-bundle for windows max or what ever your using.

Inside there is a eclipse folder go in that and there you have eclipse.exe